# Trade in services between the US and China

Tags: international-trade, balance-of-trade, china

International trade consists of both goods and services, yet in the case of US-China trade for some reason both the media and official government releases only seem to quote the goods component.

So for example for 2017 imports were $\$505.6$ bn, exports $\$130.4$bn giving a trade deficit in goods of $\$375.2$bn with China.

I cannot for the life of me find import and export figures for services to and from China.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Table 2.2 of https://www.bea.gov/scb/pdf/2017/10-October/1017-international-services-tables.pdf suggests

- US exports of services to China in 2016 worth $\$54$bn and
- US imports of services from China in 2016 worth $\$16$bn

Later parts of table 2.2 give a breakdown of types of services.  *Travel (for all purposes including education)* - which should not include transport - seems to be a large part of US exports of services to China